# How to trigger button action on leftMouseDown in Swift, Mac OSX, Cocoa

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nsbutton

I want to trigger a button on left mouse down in my mac osx app using swift.

This is the way to do it in Objective-C

```
[myButton sendActionOn:NSLeftMouseDownMask];
```

I can't figure out how to do it in Swift. Can anybody help me out with my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't have Xcode with me but it should have been the same in Swift: `myButton.sendActionOn(NSLeftMouseDownMask)`

Comment: I'm getting the error message: Use of unresolved identifier 'NSLeftMouseDownMask' if i'm trying your solution. Or do I have to import anything?

Comment: How about changing it to `NSEventType.LeftMouseDown`?

Comment: Then I'm getting this error message: Cannot invoke 'sendActionOn' with an argument list of type '(NSEventType)'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling in Xcode, this is what worked for me (Swift 2.0):

```
myButton.sendActionOn(Int(NSEventMask.LeftMouseDownMask.rawValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5:

```
myButton.sendAction(on: NSEvent.EventTypeMask.leftMouseDown)
```